# Set a delay within a for loop for animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am using the `jquery` animation function to simulate jobs being processed in a CPU. I am creating `divs` dynamically with `id = jobj` with `j` being the job number on each iteration. After which I assign the `div` element to a variable, `$process = $(#'job' + j)` for each process in the loop. What I want is for the jobs to go in the queue one at a time in 1 second time intervals. The are going into the queue in quick succession, it seems as if it is just 3 jobs based on the animation, so something is off.

This is what I have so far.

```
// Wait queue
// While jobs are using CPU, other jobs are coming in
for (j = i; j < json_process.length; j++){

    // Check if CPU is being used
    // Processes will be added to the input queue
    // First we check if the queue is empty
    if ( json_process[j].waitTime != 0 ){

        // Convert strings to numbers in the array for calculation and comparison
        completedCPUTime = parseFloat(json_process[i].completedCPUTime); // update CPU time
        joiningInputQueueTime = parseFloat(json_process[j].joiningInputQueueTime); // update joining queue time

        // Send animation[i] to input queue if it has to wait:
        if( completedCPUTime > joiningInputQueueTime && waitIndex < j){

            // Create job Div element
            elm = '<div id="job' + j + '" ' +
                    'style="background-color:red; width:5px; height:50px; position:absolute; margin-top:30px;" >' +
                    ' </div>';
            $(elm).appendTo('#animate');


                // Get process div
                var $process = $('#job' + j);
                var pos = process.offset().left; // position of process
                // The end of the queue
                var queueEnd = queue.offset().left + queue.outerWidth() - process.outerWidth();


            input_queue.push(j); // push job in input queue
            alljobs.push(j);


                    // Animate Div element $process
            // Pausing loop on each job going into queue
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Send Job joiningInputQueueTime[j] to queue div
                $process.stop().animate(
                    {left: queueEnd},
                    {duration: 1000});
            }, 5000);

            //This will keep track of the last index waiting
            waitIndexCurrent = j;

        }// End of animation condition
    }// End of wait condition
} // End of wait queue time For Loop
```

Comment: can you update your post and create a code snippet or a jsfiddle to show us your most recent code that we can run/test?

Comment: Ok will do that

Comment: or you could try reading and testing these google results first? https://www.google.com.ph/#q=javascript+delay

Comment: Thank you for your advise sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delaying inside loop irritations is impossible, but you can do something recursive like this (change number of irritations, delay and starting value as you want:

```
(function theLoop (j) {
      setTimeout(function () {
             //your code here
            if (j++ < number of irritations) {          
             theLoop(j);       
        }
      }, delay in miliseconds);
})(starting value);
```

Comment: Hello sir, could you explain why it is impossible?

Comment: @Jam1 Sorry for late answer. It's impossible because when program hit delay in for, for is not waiting for it (because it cannot recognize that something is delayed in it). If you try to call function from inside for with delay in it that's same situation. It calls function, it doesn't see delay and it's stacking function calls. Than when for is finished and delay probably passed it does rest of all functions called before in same time. So it's impossible. Same thing for while and do-while.